# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size n into shape (n,height,width)

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, data-processing

I'm doing data processing for a cnn, and my data set is the root image of the plant. When I try to reshape the minibatch set for the input of keras, I cannot reshape it.

My test is like this:

```
subset = chose_data(imgs, 1)
subset.shape
```

> (1,)

the subset only contain one image and the shape of the image is:

```
subset[0].shape
```

> (1720, 261)

the subset:

```
array([ array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ..., 
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)], dtype=object)
```

when I do

```
subset.reshape((subset.shape[0], subset[0].shape[0], subset[0].shape[1]))
```

I get the value error: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,1720,261)

the chose data method:

```
def chose_data(data, m):
    index = np.random.randint(0, len(data), size = m)
    data_rand = data[index]

    return data_rand
```

and the data load method:

```
data_dir = "/.../data/"
images = []
files = glob.glob (data_dir + "*.jpg")
for file in files:
    image = cv2.imread(file, 0)
    images.append(image)

imgs = np.array(images)
```

Comment: Notice that `subset[0].shape` is (1720, 261), but the shape of `subset` itself is just (1,) - somewhere earlier on you likely made a mistake by setting an array element with a sequence like this. You should (preferably) fix that so that you don't have the outer array at all, or use `subset[0].reshape(...)`.

Comment: yeah I agree with you, but I'm quite confused. Because my dataset images are of different resolutions, how can I handle that as a numpy array?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. How are you constructing this `subset` array in the first place?

Comment: I add the load method to my question so you can see the code. I think the mistake you mentioned is 'imgs = np.array(images)', so how can I fixt it?

Comment: Ahh I see. Maybe you could use [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.resize) to scale them all to the same size in the loading phase? NumPy does not support jagged arrays, so you're not going to have much luck trying to work with what you've got now. You either need to train them at different resolutions or consolidate them somehow.

Comment: I cannot scale them to the same size because my images area actually thin line drawings(grayscale plant root), but my CNN network can work with different size of input which is a good thing. What I don't know is how to handle the jagged arrays.

Comment: Don't put them in one big array maybe? If you can pass images of different sizes to your CNN, can't you just pass a list of image arrays instead of a NumPy array of image arrays?

Comment: But I have to make them suitable for keras, I think I may find a way:  ' np.stack(list_of_array, axis = 0) '

Comment: No Keras experience so I can't give you any advice there... good luck!

Comment: you already helped my a lot, thank you